# One image resizes properly, other does not with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.0 on the following website: [www.agrium.com/AgTracker](http://www.agrium.com/AgTracker)

The problem I am having is that when the browser window is resized or when a user is using a tablet/phone, the two logos at the very top of the page are not displaying as I would like.

Below I am showing this behaviour using Chrome on my desktop.

Situation #1: full screen display, logos are spread out and full size. I'm happy with this.
[image]

Situation #2: screen size is decreased, but logos are still full size. I would like for either the logos to stay on the same line and for the logos to scale (shrink).
[image]

Situation #3: this would likely be solved by whatever fixes situation #2, but I just wanted to show that if I shrink the browser width further, the Agrium logo has scaled (yay!) but the AgTracker logo has not (boooo).

[image]

Any help with updating the CSS or way I am using Bootstrap that allows for the logos to both scale and remain on the same line would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `media queries` to solve this: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: The problem is that when the two spans you are using `span4` and `span8` get to a certain width, they clear eachother's `float` and they get 100% width and that is why you see them in two rows. I would know how to fix this in a hackish way, but I wouldn't post it as an answer as it's a lot of code and not practical... I rather wait to see if any quality help shows up here sooner than later. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem:

1. At first, you should recognize that the first two images are actually not two but just a single image. Using this technique, you can make a single png or jpg file with all these three images in combined into a single image file. I would not recommend this, so I would like to propose a much more robust solution using CSS. Please look at my second point.
2. You can use CSS3's in built feature known as CSS3 Media Queries.
   This technology allows you to create responsive websites and be able
   to dictate how your content appears on a variety of devices like
   mobile, tabs or desktops.

Comment: How exactly does using a media query here help? I know how it works, but I'm curious to know how it to achieve exactly what @MichaelFreake wants to do with his project. If you have 2 images like that side by side is there a way to keep one to the left and one to the right and when they meet in the middle they shrink instead of flow to the next line?

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle to get the scenario rolling. I added background color and some ID attributes for easier selectors. http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/ZKzbh/ I also added some media queries there to see how to go about solving this with that.